# Firefox adds google analytics data(utm) into cookie

Tags: php, http, firefox, cookies

I have a client application runs as Unity WebPlayer, Unity WebPlayer WWW module uses ajax like requests over browser.

I made a simple http request which at first receives **Set-Cookie** or **SET-COOKIE** from **responseheader** and adds that information as **Cookie** in further **requestheaders**.

In Chrome everything works smoothly.

But in Firefox, when I add Cookie information, Firefox adds some more into cookie before sending. It adds __utma->__utmz data which is Google Analytics Tracking cookie infos.

I guess this addition messes up whole cookie system. Because afterwards,in every response server keeps sending Set-Cookie again & again without __utma->__utmz, which my Client doesnt agree with.

I only have Firebug & Firecookie plugins on Firefox.

**Update : It also works okay on IE just like Chrome does.**

**Firefox**
[image: Firefox]
**Chrome**
[image: Chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a separate cookie.

Your server should still be able to parse out and use the cookies it is interested in, and ignore all others.